# AudioUnitRender Error -50 meaning

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession, audiounit, remoteio

I get an Error -50 in AudioUnitRender call. My Audio Unit is simply a RemoteIO unit getting samples from the mic. What is the meaning of error -50?

```
  let status = AudioUnitRender(controller.audioUnit!, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, listPtr)

if noErr != status {
    print("Error \(status)");
    fatalError("Render status \(status)")
  // return status;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-50 (`kAudio_ParamError`) means one of the parameters you passed is wrong.

A common error with `AudioUnitRender` is to pass an `AudioBufferList` with the wrong number of `mNumberBuffers` (you may be recording non-interleaved stereo) or the `AudioBuffer`s themselves may be the wrong size or have the wrong number of channels.

I encounter this problem whenever I forget that the simulator and device remote audio units have different default stream formats and don't explicitly set them via

```
AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &streamFormatIActuallyWant, UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size))
```

I *think* the simulator defaults to interleaved integer and the device defaults to non interleaved float, although maybe that's just my configuration.

From the `AudioUnitRender` header file:

> The caller must provide a valid ioData AudioBufferList that matches the
>   expected topology for the current audio format for the given bus. The buffer
>   list can be of two variants:
>   (1) If the mData pointers are non-null then the audio unit will render its
>   output into those buffers. These buffers should be aligned to 16 byte
>   boundaries (which is normally what malloc will return).
>   (2) If the mData pointers are null, then the audio unit can provide pointers
>   to its own buffers. In this case the audio unit is required to keep those
>   buffers valid for the duration of the calling thread's I/O cycle

By passing null `mData` (point (2)) can save you an unnecessary copy, but you still need to know the format "topology", which is just `mNumberBuffers`  (probably 1 or 2).

Comment: How do I pass an AudioBufferList with nil mData, I try but it again gives -50 error.

Comment: My configuration is complex. I have AVCaptureSession as well. I reproduce -50 error as follows. Start the app and quit it before AVCaptureSession is initialized. I see everything setup in background. Now the moment I bring the app to foreground, I start getting -50 error. No idea how to debug it.

Comment: Do you have a project on github you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately it is only showing in my app which is complex. I am trying to make a sample app which reproduces the issue but it is hard. Will keep you posted as soon as I recreate minimal sample code.

Comment: I see the problem occurs when inNumberFrames parameter is odd length (1115 instead of 1114). I don't know how inNumberFrames changes from 1024 to 1114 or 1115 after interruption. Any ideas what influences this param?

Comment: I have added a new question with code that is very specific, please have a look and let me know your inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52061575/audiounitrender-error-50-with-odd-length-buffers

Comment: For the funny buffer sizes, it sounds like the `AVAudioSession` sampling rate was changed. You can try and change it back I guess, but your code should ideally deal with non-preferred settings as you're not guaranteed to get what you ask for.

Comment: Yes I change it back to 44100 when my AVCaptureSession resumes, but I find that all buffers are 1115 in length continuously in my Swift app setup. In Objective C project, everything works and I get inNumberBuffers alternating between 1114 and 1115. I have no idea what causes 1115 buffer size continuously in Swift code. Rather than looking code line by line, I am trying to identify the place where things go wrong.

Comment: There's a sample rate converter between you and the hardware - `1024*48000/44100 = 1114.5...` frames, hence the alternating between 1114 and 1115.

Comment: But where is this 48000 coming from? The mic defaults to 44100 as far as I know. When there is category change from playback to record, why is number of frames not reset to 1024?

Comment: Ok I have good news. I have reproducible sample code that is minimal. Should I share it with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179032/discussion-between-rhythmic-fistman-and-deepak-sharma).

Comment: sent you a message in chat

Comment: where do you find that error code -50 corresponds to kAudio_ParamError. the documentation of apple is just useless https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1440513-audiooutputunitstop (A result code. hahahahaha)

Comment: You can either use https://www.osstatus.com or grep header files. It's not great. Also I think -50 has been a parameter error on the mac for a loooooooooong time, like 25+ years.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you pass an AudioBufferList with enough `mDataByteSize`, it should large than the inNumberFrames * channel.