# Swift vs Objective C pointer manipulation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4, core-audio

I have this code in Objective C which works fine:

```
list = controller->audioBufferList;
list->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*kSampleWordSize;
list->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*kSampleWordSize;
```

And it works fantastic, it updates mDataByteSize field of mBuffers[0] & mBuffers[1]. I tried translating the same in Swift but it doesn't work:

```
public var audioBufferList:UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer
```

In function,

```
let listPtr = controller.audioBufferList.unsafeMutablePointer

let buffers = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &listPtr.pointee.mBuffers, count: Int(listPtr.pointee.mNumberBuffers))

for var buf in buffers {
    buf.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * UInt32(sampleWordSize)
    NSLog("Data byte size \(buf.mDataByteSize)")
}

for buf in buffers {
    NSLog("Data byte size \(buf.mDataByteSize)")
}
```

The mDataByteSize is not updated. The NSLog on reading back in second for loop points to original values, not updated ones. It seems var buf is referring to another buf by making a copy. How do I fix it? It's a pure Swift language issue that I am not able to understand.

EDIT: As pointed out by Martin, I fixed the issue by modifying the for loop as

```
 for i in 0..<Int(listPtr.pointee.mNumberBuffers) {
    buffers[i].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * UInt32(sampleWordSize)
}
```

Now it works. But that has further aroused my curiosity in Swift Language, how non intuitive it is and how irritating it is for developers who use pointers to manipulate stuff. Why do the following loops fail? Are the var buffers copy by value?

```
     for buf in buffers {
         var buffer = buf
         buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * UInt32(sampleWordSize)
     }
```

Or

```
    for var buf in buffers {
        buf.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * UInt32(sampleWordSize)
    }
```

EDIT 2: Hamish's answer raises doubts about validity of using listPtr anywhere. I was using listPtr in a number of calls, such as:

```
let status = AudioUnitRender(controller.audioUnit!, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, listPtr)
```

I now need to know where can we use listPtr and where we can not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the call:

```
let buffers = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &listPtr.pointee.mBuffers, count: Int(listPtr.pointee.mNumberBuffers))
```

`&listPtr.pointee.mBuffers` produces a temporary pointer valid only for the duration of the call to `UnsafeBufferPointer`'s initialiser. Therefore attempting to use the buffer pointer results in *undefined behaviour* (the compiler [will hopefully warn on such cases](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20467) in Swift 5.1).

Instead, you can iterate directly over `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer`, as it conforms to `MutableCollection`.

For example:

```
for index in audioBufferList.indices {
  audioBufferList[index].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * UInt32(sampleWordSize)
  print("Data byte size \(audioBufferList[index].mDataByteSize)")
}

for buffer in audioBufferList {
  print("Data byte size \(buffer.mDataByteSize)")
}
```

Comment: But I never get a compiler warning. There is no need to use the pointer or buffer list outside the scope of the function & I am not doing it. Do you mean it's going to cause undefined behavior? I would like to understand it better.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Indeed, you won't get a warning yet, as that hasn't been implemented yet – I'm hoping to get it done for Swift 5.1. The scope the pointer is valid for is the call to `UnsafeBufferPointer`'s initialiser *itself*, which ends upon the assignment to `let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(...)` – so any code that uses `buffer` will exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: Bam, but that complicated the problem further. I need to use the buffer list pointer in call to AudioUnitRender(). You mean it is unsafe to use the pointer in AudioUnitRender?

Comment: @DeepakSharma You should be able to use the `unsafeMutablePointer` property on `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` for that, i.e `audioBufferList.unsafeMutablePointer`. That'll work as long as the `UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` remains valid.

Comment: Ok final question, why does the scope of pointer let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(...) ends right after the call? Any references to readup on this?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a whole lot of documentation for these argument conversions. There is however a blog post on the subject: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6 (see the paragraph headed "Safety with Pointer Argument Conversions").

Comment: I read it, but if the pointer is not valid after the call, what is the use of such a call? It reminds me of weak var in ARC where it gets deallocated immediately after alloc/init call. Also, it's not clear which pointers suffer with this anomaly and which do not. I read about pointers returned by withUnsafeBytes call as potentially unsafe, not sure why it applies to UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(...)?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Ah okay, I *think* I see where your confusion lies. There's nothing inherently wrong with the initialiser call `UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(...)`, you can use it just fine by passing in an existing pointer with a count. However with `UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &listPtr.pointee.mBuffers, count: Int(listPtr.pointee.mNumberBuffers))` you're not passing in an existing pointer. Swift sees that you're trying to pass the inout expression `&listPtr.pointee.mBuffers` to a pointer parameter, so creates a *temporary* pointer value.

Comment: That pointer value is only valid for the duration of the call it is passed to, which in this case is `UnsafeBufferPointer.init`. But `UnsafeBufferPointer.init` returns a new buffer pointer that stores the base pointer you passed in. However this pointer is no longer valid, therefore any attempt to use the buffer pointer leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Not sure I follow. Would this example help clarify things? https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/a3adaec3009fe2af4f22e845d680fa1c. **Edit:** Looks like you got it :) I'll leave this here in case it's useful to anyone else.

Comment: OMG, looks like I need to review my whole app code now. Coming from C background, this "temporary pointer" creation is all new to me. Not sure how many parts of my code may have undefined behavior!

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yeah, unfortunately it's an incredibly deceptive footgun that's [accidentally misused quite a lot](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20070#issuecomment-434405701). Things will be better once there's a compiler warning to catch them :) It would also be Nice™ if the UB sanitiser could catch them (as well as others that can't be detected by simple static analysis)...

Comment: I am going through this topic very carefully, you used two terms "existing pointer" and Swift inferring inout expression &listPtr.pointee.mBuffers. I understand Swift creates a temporary pointer for anything except global or static variables when they are passed to functions.  &listPtr.pointee.mBuffers will be no exception so a temporary pointer will be created for it when initializer UnsafeBufferPointer.init is called. What is that you referred to as "existing pointer" & how Swift infers it as inout?

Comment: @DeepakSharma When I say "existing", I just mean any existing `UnsafePointer` variable you might pass as an argument. An "inout expression" is just any expression prefixed with `&` – it's not something that's inferred.

Comment: Ok I got it. Coming to this temporary pointer phenomenon, who generates this temporary pointer - Swift Runtime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184477/discussion-between-hamish-and-deepak-sharma).